# "The source 'IQueryable' doesn't implement 'IAsyncEnumerable" Only sources that implement 'IAsyncEnumerable'

Tags: entity-framework-core, iqueryable, ef-core-3.1

getting the following error:

> The source 'IQueryable' doesn't implement
> 'IAsyncEnumerable'.
> Only sources that implement 'IAsyncEnumerable' can be used for Entity
> Framework asynchronous operations."

The function that is being called needs to return an IQueryable.

My code (simplified):

```
IQueryable<StockDto> search;

xxxService myService = new xxxService(_database, cancellationToken);
MakesDto resp = await myService.GetMakes();

search = resp.make.AsQueryable()
.Select((e) =>
    new StockDto {
        Make = e.value
    }).Distinct();
```

I don't think the Dto definitions are overly relevant here however I am happy to provide anything else you think is important. Any ideas where to from here?

Comment: A soon as you give us an incomplete sample like this, the problem is, *you* don't know if it exhibits the same problem you're asking about. Because neither you nor anyone else has attempted to compile or execute this code. That's why we usually ask for a [mcve]

Comment: Async methods you can apply ONLY to `IQueryable` returned by `DbContext`. Applying async methods to `IQueryable` which made from `IEnumerable` has absolutely no sense and will not work.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv got it. There’s some business logic that attempts to either pull the data from dbcontext or alternatively an external service. I was hoping I could return IQueryable in the same format as the previous, sounds like I may need to rework the entire thing.